# Possible to Run iOS Apps on PC

Tags: ios, iphone

Is it possible to run iOS Apps DIRECTLY on Mac OS? What about Windows? Or do you always have to use a virtual machine? I searched around and all I found was people saying you need to use a virtual machine. Reason for this: I want to automate behavior on an app on my iphone, and I think that will be much faster on my PC.

Comment: How can I improve this question?

Comment: Are you asking about running automated (UI or unit) tests for your iOS app?

Comment: You can run iOS apps on a Mac using the simulator *if you have the source code and can compile it for x86*. You cannot run App Store apps on the simulator because they will not be compiled x86. You cannot run App Store apps or Simulator apps on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS SDK accesses the hardware of the iPhone/iPad. It's very specific hardware which is not available on any other device.
The CPU is different, the display, device buttons, sensors and phone specific stuff...

The simulator simulates all this hardware, still it needs a different compile and can not execute the iOS bundle as it does not simulate the Arm CPU architecture.

That said, it does not make much sense to do automated test on another platform than the target platform, as the app might have slightly different errors and behavior.